# Extract all values in a certain year of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to obtain all values that have a certain year in the following pandas `DataFrame` instance:

```
timestamps = np.array([pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2016-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')])
quantities = np.array([1.0, 10.0, 2.0, 3.0])
data = dict(timestamps=timestamps, quantities=quantities)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

which looks like this:

```
  timestamps  quantities
0 2016-01-01         1.0
2 2016-01-02         10.0
3 2017-01-01         2.0
4 2018-01-01         3.0
```

I want to extract all the `quantities` attribute that have a certain year, i.e. for 2016 I would get [1.0, 10.0]?

Comment: Use `df.loc[df.timestamps.dt.year.eq(2016), 'quantities'].values.tolist()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the year of the `timestamps` column using [`dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html).

Here `dt` is an accessor object for datetimelike properties. Hence enables applying vectorized methods on a datetime Series.

Then simply use the result to index the dataframe:

```
df[df.timestamps.dt.year.eq(2016)]

 timestamps      quantities
0 2016-01-01         1.0
1 2016-01-02        10.0
```